# Doesn't the massless $g\phi^4$ theory bound to have an infrared fixed point?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, scale-invariance

A free, massless scalar theory, $\mathcal{L}_1=\frac{1}{2}(\partial\phi)^2$, is scale-invariant both classically and quantum mechanically. However, a $g\phi^4$ theory, $\mathcal{L}_2=\frac{1}{2}(\partial\phi)^2-\frac{g}{4}\phi^4$, is not because even though the Lagrangian is scale-invariant the Greens functions are not.

Does that not mean, by continuity, that a massless $\phi^4$ theory is bound to have a (infrared) fixed point at $g=0$ in the usual sense of vanishing beta function at $g=0$ (at low energies) and flowing into the corresponding scale-invariant free, massless theory at low energies?

I do not have much knowledge of this at this point. But I do know that solving the one-loop beta function, we get $$g=\frac{g_0}{1-\frac{3g_0}{16\pi^2}\ln(\mu/\mu_0)}$$ where $g_0$ is the coupling at some reference scale $\mu_0$. This has a Landau pole like singularity at a finite energy scale $\mu=\mu_0\exp[16\pi^2/3g_0]$. Does that mean the expectation of flowing into an infrared fixed point, by continuity, was flawed?

Comment: I can't tell what your continuity argument is supposed to be.

Comment: I mean, in the massless interacting theory ($\mathcal{L}_2$), if we put $g=0$, we get the massless noninteracting theory $(\mathcal{L}_1)$. Now, the coupling $g$ varies with scale and in particular, it increases with the energy scale. Doesn't that mean $g\phi^4$ theory must have a fixed point at a low-energy where the coupling $g0$ goes to zero?

Comment: essentially yes. In 4d the theory is believed to be trivial. This is related to $g$ blowing up (in finite time, by Landau's argument) when running the RG flow backwards toward the UV. If you run the RG normally towards the IR then indeed you end up at the $g=0$ free massless theory. Said differently, if you have a critical model on the lattice and zoom out the continuum QFT you get is the free massless theory.

Comment: @AbdelmalekAbdesselam I could not understand. How did you avoid the Landau pole like singularity?

Comment: @mithusengupta123: keep in mind the direction in which you are following the renormalization group flow towards the UV (backward) versus towards the IR (forward). Towards the UV you will encounter the Landau singularity, but towards the IR you will not and you will flow towards the free massless theory.